# Update values in one table based on values in another table where a specific criteria matches

Tags: ms-access

I have picked up the query from another thread posted here and have edited based on the tables I have. I get some syntax error when I try to save it. What am I doing wrong here?

```
    UPDATE cleanedGC
    SET cleanedGC.Competency = DomainMapTBL.[Person SMU Name] 
    From cleanedGC, DomainMapTBL
    WHERE cleanedGC.[Person SMU #]=DomainMapTBL.[Person SMU]
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct syntax would be:

```
UPDATE cleanedGC 
INNER JOIN DomainMapTBL 
ON cleanedGC.[Person SMU #]=DomainMapTBL.[Person SMU]
SET cleanedGC.Competency = DomainMapTBL.[Person SMU Name]
```